# Bootstrap and CakePHP - Custom bootstrap css is ignored by form files

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp

I am developing a web application using cakePHP with bootstrap.
I have downloaded the bootstrap css to customize the looks and imported the files accordingly, within bootstrap.ctp:

It works fine for the index.ctp files but the form files (e.g add.ctp) ignore the styles completely.

Comment: This is rather difficult to diagnose. Do you use firebug - it is extremely helpful to understand how the styles are being rendered? Is the CSS being loaded i.e, does your forms use the same template as the other working pages?

Comment: You need to give us more information. Add relevant code and generated HTML and any other CSS rules that apply

Comment: Did you use the [BoostCake plugin](http://slywalker.github.io/cakephp-plugin-boost_cake/)?

Comment: "The problem" is how your'e loading the css file - you've used a relative url, and are not using the Html helper

Answer (score 0):

Just add a couple of parameters in the input options, for example:

Create from:

```
echo $this->Form->create('User',array('class'=>'form-horizontal'));
```

and form fields

```
echo $this -> Form -> input('name', array(
                            'error'=>array('notempty'=>__('This field cannot be left blank',true)),
                            'class'=>'form-control',
                            'label'=>array('text'=>__('Name',true),'class'=>'col-lg-2 control-label'),
                            'div'=>array('class'=>'form-group'),
                            'between'=>'<div class="col-lg-4">',
                            'after' =>'</div>'));
```

Or use one of the available bootstrap helpers.

Thanks to the excellent CakePHP documentation, you can read more about the options:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#options

Answer (score 0):

thank you all. 
I now followed the instructions in the HtmlHelper concerning the css() function and it works now. I modified the path to the css within bootstrap.ctp accordingly:

```
echo $this->Html->css(array('bootstrap.css', 'bootstrap.min.css'));
```